# How do I actually make use of the kvm-clock clock driver?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, kvm, clock

According to copious sources, the KVM clock driver is loaded as shown here:

```
 cat /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

These sources all seem to think that this necessarily means that guest VM running Linux is deriving its clock values from this clock driver. My experience is that it is not. Several independent tests show that compared to the host clock and a network time source, the guest OS clock is off by as much as 3 seconds per day. The `hwclock` program is also used to confirm this. Is there some additional step required to obtain the current_clocksource? Or is the problem elsewhere? Or should the `tsc` driver be used?